# Angular - Toggle on/off divs

Tags: angularjs

[Please see this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o4z3cyhx/3/)

Within this fiddle I have two html divs that contain Ad Placements. I want to toggle them on/off using Angular so on one instance Ad 1 will show and in another instance Ad 2 will show instead. Note that in each div I have Javascript content that I want to also toggle on/off.

I essentially want to update the View.

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCntrl">
        <div id = "ad1" class = "ad1">
            AD 1
            <img src ="http://images.dailytech.com/frontpage/fp__Apple-100x100.png"></img>
            <script><!-- code here --></</script>
        </div>

        <div id = "ad2" class = "ad2">
            AD 2
            <img src ="http://fixmypod.ca/image/cache/data/NEWEST_Phones/Samsung_Galaxy_Note_2-100x100.jpg"></img>
            <script><!-- code here --></</script>
        </div>

</div>
```

Angular:

```
var app = angular.module('HelloApp', []);

app.controller('MyCtrl',['$scope','$element', function($scope, $element) {

  $scope.changeView = function(ad){
      //make ad x show and the other ad hidden
   }

}]);
```

How can I go on doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use [`ng-show`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) instead of a class and use a boolean property on your scope to trigger your divs.

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCntrl">
    <div id="ad1" ng-show="toggle">
        AD 1
        <img src ="http://images.dailytech.com/frontpage/fp__Apple-100x100.png"></img>
        <script><!-- code here --></</script>
    </div>
    <div id="ad2" ng-show="!toggle">
        AD 2
        <img src ="http://fixmypod.ca/image/cache/data/NEWEST_Phones/Samsung_Galaxy_Note_2-100x100.jpg"></img>
        <script><!-- code here --></</script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Angular:

```
var app = angular.module('HelloApp', []);

app.controller('MyCtrl',['$scope','$element', function($scope, $element) {
    $scope.toggle = true;
    $scope.changeView = function(ad){
        $scope.toggle = !$scope.toggle;
    }
}]);
```

Alternatively, you can use `ng-include` to only render a template based on a property.

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCntrl">
    <div ng-if="condition">
        <div ng-include="`template/path/ad1`"></div>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="!condition">
        <div ng-include="`template/path/ad2`"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is changing the visibility the best option? I thought there would be a way to dynamically switch templates/partials in an angular way

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to accomplish and from what you had posted, it looked liked visibility.  If you had said "I only want to load one ad depending on the user's browser", obviously visibility would have been less preferable.  I've updated my answer to include switching templates.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by

- [ngShow](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow)
- [ngHide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide)
- [ngIf](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)

**controller**

```
$scope.myDiv=true;
```

**view**

```
<div ng-show="myDiv">
  if true this will visible
</div>
```